# Error trying to resolve dependency using Ninject Factory extensions

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a Web API project where I am trying to resolve a query handler at runtime given the query type and query result type. Below is some test code I am using as a proof of concept. I am using the Ninject Factory extension but I am having trouble getting the correct setup as I want to return a generic interface, maybe this is the wrong design so any suggestions would be grateful.

Code

```
public interface IQueryHandlerFactory
{ 
    IQueryHandler<IQuery, IQueryResult> Resolve(Type type);
}

public interface IQuery
{
}

public interface IQueryResult
{
}

public interface IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>
    where TQuery : IQuery
    where TResult : IQueryResult
{
    TResult Execute(TQuery query);
}

public class PaymentQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<GetPayments, PaymentResult>
{
    public PaymentResult Execute(GetPayments query)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class UserQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<GetUsers, UserResult>
{
    public UserResult Execute(GetUsers query)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class TypeInstanceProvider : StandardInstanceProvider
{
    protected override Type GetType(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments)
    {
        var type = arguments[0] as Type;

        return type;
    }

    protected override IConstructorArgument[] GetConstructorArguments(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments)
    {
        return base.GetConstructorArguments(methodInfo, arguments).Skip(1).ToArray();
    }

    public override object GetInstance(IInstanceResolver instanceResolver, MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments)
    {
        Type t = this.GetType(methodInfo, arguments);

        var test = instanceResolver.Get(t,
                                null,
                                null,
                                this.GetConstructorArguments(methodInfo, arguments),
                                false);

        return test;
    }
}
```

I am just testing with some Ninject calls in my NinjectWebCommon for now to see if it would work. I want to be able to use the `MakeGenericType` method as I know the query type and result type. It works when I call `var test = kernel.Get(queryHandlerType);` however it fails when I try to use the factory below

NinjectWebCommon code:

```
kernel.Bind<IQueryHandlerFactory>().ToFactory(() => new TypeInstanceProvider());

var queryHandlerType = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(GetPayments), typeof(PaymentResult));
var factory = kernel.Get<IQueryHandlerFactory>();

var test = kernel.Get(queryHandlerType); // This works
var handler = factory.Resolve(queryHandlerType); // This fails
```

The error that is generated is below

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in DynamicProxyGenAssembly2

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'PaymentQueryHandler' to type 'IQueryHandler`2[IQuery,IQueryResult]'.
```

I may well be over complicating things, or is this even possible? I would have that it is. Has anyone any suggestions to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you're overcomplicating things indeed. What's the point of the factory? If `kernel.Get(queryHandlerType)` works, why don't you use it?

How about this very simple implementation:

```
public interface IQueryHandlerFactory
{ 
    IQueryHandler<TQuery, TQueryResult>()
        where TQuery : IQuery, TQueryResult : IQueryResult;
}

public class QueryHandlerFactory : IQueryHandlerFactory
{
    private readonly IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot;
    public QueryHandlerFactory(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
    {
        this.resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
    }

    IQueryHandler<TQuery, TQueryResult>()
        where TQuery : IQuery, TQueryResult : IQueryResult
    {
        var queryHandlerType = typeof(IQueryHandler<TQuery,TQueryResult>);
        return (IQueryHandler<TQuery, TQueryResult>)kernel.Get(queryHandlerType);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say it won't work at all.

The problem is that the dynamically created factory uses `provider.GetInstance` method to return your object. And then it tries to cast it to target interface.

It means that in your example it does something the following:

```
var obj = // your PaymentQueryHandler object
(IQueryHandler<IQuery, IQueryResult>)obj
```

But it won't work because your interface doesn't enable [covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) by applying `out modifier`.

But even here you have a problem. Your interface uses first generic argument and an input type and second generic argument as an output argument. It means that you need to enable [contravariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484.aspx). But in that case you won't be able to convert your type because you need to convert it into more derived type.

That's why it doesn't work with you factory.

And it works with the standard `get` call, because it knows a target type and doesn't use casting to `IQueryHandler<IQuery, IQueryResult>`.

Comment: So even without applying covariance etc. I still have a problem. I can modify my solution to suit my needs so do you recommend an alternative approach using providers etc or do you see the same problem arising? If I injected the kernel (I know,I know) would it at least work?

Comment: Yes, try to use providers instead.

Comment: My only concern with providers is that I run into the casting issue again. Having never used them before, have you an example where I can pass in the generic type (from the MakeGenericType call) as a parameter?

Comment: I don't have an example that you want (I will need to write it from scratch). But two questions: 1) why you cannot use kernel to inject your queryhandler into your class and use it? 2) Do you really need to have a different realization `IQueryHanlder` but with different type arguments?